# tsc unknown compiler option allowNonTsExtensions

Tags: typescript, tsc

I am getting `error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'allowNonTsExtensions'` when trying to run `tsc` on a project.

Here is my `tsconfig.json` file.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "allowNonTsExtensions": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmitOnError": false,
    "rootDir": ".",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": false
}
```

Using `typescript@1.6.2` globally in `npm`.

Link to the [project](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/getting-started/tutorial/) being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option is not defined for `tsconfig.json`. You can check it in [wiki](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/tsconfig.json) or in the source code:

- https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/compiler/commandLineParser.ts#L477 - parsing method
- https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/src/compiler/commandLineParser.ts#L9 - the list of options

`allowNonTsExtensions` is an option that is a part of [compiler API](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API#transpiling-single-file) that is internal.

Comment: This is the default configuration for a tutorial from the ionic framework. Why would they have included this if it does not exist?

Comment: It's hard to tell without further information. The link for the tutorial would be appreciated. However, `allowNonTsExtensions` option is useful in the scenario *Let's try to write a barebones compiler that will take a list of TypeScript files and compile down to their corresponding JavaScript.* (https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Compiler-API) So the option is not for normal TypeScript apps but for custom transpilation scripts themselves (i.e. when `tsc` is not enough for you).

Comment: Here is the link to the tutorial http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/getting-started/tutorial/

Comment: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2-starter-tutorial/commit/bd1fa4cf3f3f5c5077c70a8a2c9c353d830399c2 - `tsconfig.json` was removed three days ago as *unused file*

Comment: Well it is still there. I just ran `ionic start MyProject tutorial --v2` yesterday. I am going to run again and see what happens.

Comment: They may use some versioning (as for example npm does). The change I referred to was done in the master branch. I guess they have to release it.

Comment: Yeah, `tsconfig.json` is still there. Thanks for the help, i will try to figure out when that change is going to be pushed out. Will probably try to delete the config file and see what happens.