# Ionic 2 in vs2015 build error

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ionic2

Just tried to import a basic ionic 2 app into vs2015, the same way as a ionic 1 app.  But when i build the ionic 2 app i get build errors. Seem to be associated with typescript.  Anyone managed to get an ionic 2 app building in vs2015. Maybe to early as still beta.

error:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   TS5023  Build: Unknown compiler option 'allowNonTsExtensions'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [tsc unknown compiler option allowNonTsExtensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33785337/tsc-unknown-compiler-option-allownontsextensions) regarding the unknown compiler option.

Create a new Ionic2 typescript project from scratch and import it into VS

`ionic start MyIonic2Project --v2 --ts`

If this works it will just be an issue with your project's setup, as opposed to VS compatibility with Ionic 2 at this early stage.

At a guess your project is using Typescript in *.js files and has allowNonTsExtensions set in tsconfig.json. In which case you should move typescript to *.ts files, and remove allowNonTsExtensions from tsconfig.json.